# How to tell if hard drive is healthy after corruption

Tags: hard-drive

I bought a WD hard drive for use in my NAS storage. Sadly, it turned out I got the wrong one for NAS storage (there is a red and a green).

Any way, the hard drive got corrupted, data loss etc. I can live with that and as such, my question is about the health of that hard drive.

Does the fact it had this corruption indicate the hard drive itself is broken or that is just wasn't used in the correct manner and is fine! I'm hoping I can just reformat it and use it as a hard drive in my computer.

My question is, how do I ascertain if the drive itself is healtyh?

Comment: Hard drives don’t corrupt data just because you put them in a NAS. I have multiple WD Green that are now at 35 000 power-on hours and still going strong. One failed completely recently, but it did *not*, in its entire lifetime, exhibit checksum errors with ZFS.

Comment: @DanielB, but, can it wear it out? I mean, there is a red and green versioin (meaning a NAS and PC) so I assume the hard drive has been designed for purpose. As such, maybe instead of corrupt I mean wear out. Although that still doesn't make sense based upon your comment... Both of my WD green failed in my NAS system, one of them shows as ~50% health via a SMART tool, the other isn't even recognised :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test it. There are plenty of HDD testing tools for that purpose. I've used MHDD (available in Hiren's cd) - you boot from Hiren's, navigate through the menu, detect all your HDDs and simply run a test, smartmontools (you'll have to boot a live Linux cd, or attach the disk to a Linux workstation, view your disk with `fidsk -l`, and scan the one you want to check with `smartctl -t long /dev/sdX`, you will be able to see the result from the scan with `smartctl -a /dev/sdX`).

Comment: It's odd, the SMART tool said it was fine (I used Acronis Drive Monitor)... But, as per my other post, I've had files just disappear! http://superuser.com/questions/1163247/a-folder-has-disappeared ... Would you still trust the SMART tool?

Comment: What is the count of `reallocated sectors` when you view the disk information with `smartctl -a /dev/sdX`?